# Bootstrap script deploys app using yum, how can I deploy on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, yum, apt-get

I am deploying an application that has a bootstrap script, which installs a bunch of packages using yum. However, I am deploying on Ubuntu Maverick. Does is make sense to upgrade the script to use apt-get instead. I installed yum on ubuntu, but not sure how to configure repositories and such, plus I am not sure if continuing with yum is the right approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's most likely best to upgrade the script to use apt-get unless it is a really long script. Most users will not want to go through the hassel of installing yum.

Comment: That's what made sense to me too, but was not sure, thanks.  In my case this was on an ec2 instance and I switched to a centos image from an ubuntu image.